# Meu formulário em ajax não valida

Tags: html5, ajax

Estou tentando validar um formulário por ajax e não está funcionando.

Pagina ajax está assim: http://pastebin.com/t5it0n4T

```
 jQuery('#enviar-contato').click(function(){        
    var _name = jQuery('#name').val();
    var _email = jQuery('#email').val();
    var _assunto = jQuery('#assunto').val();
    var _message = jQuery('#message').val();

    /* construindo url */

    var urlData = {
     "name"    : _name,
     "email"   : _email,
     "assunto" : _assunto,
     "message" : _message
   };

   jQuery.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "formcontato.php",
    data: urlData,          
    success: function( resultado )
    {
      console.log(resultado);
    }
  });
});
```

Pagina contato: http://pastebin.com/44raVzk6

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 box-contact-send" style="display: none;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <p class="form-control border-green">Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso. Obrigado.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="sr-only">Nome</label>
                <span class="icon-user"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nome" required></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                <span class="icon-mail"><input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject" class="sr-only">Assunto</label>
                <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control subject" id="subject" placeholder="Assunto" required> -->
                <select class="form-control subject" name="assunto" id="assunto" required>
                    <option value="Dúvidas">Dúvidas</option>
                    <option value="Orçamento">Orçamento</option>
                    <option value="Parcerias">Parcerias</option>
                    <option value="Sugestões">Sugestões</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="sr-only">Mensagem</label>
                <textarea class="form-control message" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Mensagem" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="enviar-contato" class="btn btn-form btn-cta-primary" value="Enviar Mensagem">
</form>
```

Alguém sabe porque não ta validando?

Obs.: Coloquei required que é uma validação em HTML5 e nem isso funciona.

Comment: Aqui está normal: https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/qw2z6k1j/

Comment: Tens o jQuery adicionado na página? em que parte da página estás a correr esse código? antes ou depois da form?

Comment: Tem sim, olha ai completo com o jquery no final. http://pastebin.com/wnfkcapD

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow, utilize o botão `Comentar` para adicionar comentários a sua perguntas ou a respostas, use o botão [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/73814/edit) para editar sua pergunta e adicionar mais informações. O botão `Responder` é exclusivo para respostas. Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo site, para conhecer mais.

Comment: @user27508 você declarou o tipo de documento no início do arquivo `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de colocar o evento no `input type="submit"` trate o `submit` do formulário, para que as validações html5 funcionem corretamente.

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
   var _name = jQuery('#name').val();
    var _email = jQuery('#email').val();
    var _assunto = jQuery('#assunto').val();
    var _message = jQuery('#message').val();

    /* construindo url */

    var urlData = {
     "name"    : _name,
     "email"   : _email,
     "assunto" : _assunto,
     "message" : _message
   };

   jQuery.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "formcontato.php",
    data: urlData,          
    success: function( resultado )
    {
      console.log(resultado);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 box-contact-send" style="display: none;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <p class="form-control border-green">Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso. Obrigado.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="sr-only">Nome</label>
                <span class="icon-user"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nome" required></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                <span class="icon-mail"><input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject" class="sr-only">Assunto</label>
                <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control subject" id="subject" placeholder="Assunto" required> -->
                <select class="form-control subject" name="assunto" id="assunto" required>
                    <option value="Dúvidas">Dúvidas</option>
                    <option value="Orçamento">Orçamento</option>
                    <option value="Parcerias">Parcerias</option>
                    <option value="Sugestões">Sugestões</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="sr-only">Mensagem</label>
                <textarea class="form-control message" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Mensagem" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="enviar-contato" class="btn btn-form btn-cta-primary" value="Enviar Mensagem">
</form>
```

Você ainda pode "serializar" ([`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)) do formulário sem necessidade de criar o objeto `urlData` na mão, o `serialize()` cria um objeto json com o atributo `name` e o `value` dos campos do formulário;

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var urlData = $(this).serialize();
   $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "formcontato.php",
    data: urlData,          
    success: function(resultado)
    {
      console.log(resultado);
    }
  });
});
```